# Where is the mistake: On the sum of two prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Someone could help me find some error in the reasoning:

We know, that the canonical decomposition of $n!$ is:

$\displaystyle n!=\prod_{p_{i}\leq n}p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}(n)}$, where:

$\displaystyle \alpha_{i}(n)=\sum_{t=1}^{r}\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p_{i}^{t}}\right \rfloor$.

It's possible use the canonical decomposition of $n!$ to found the canonical decomposition of $n$, let's see:

$$n=\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}=\frac{\displaystyle \prod_{p_{i}\leq n}p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}(n)}}{\displaystyle \prod_{p_{i}\leq n-1}p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}(n-1)}}$$

$\displaystyle n=\prod_{p_{i}\leq n}p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}(n)-\alpha_{i}(n-1)}=\prod_{p_{i}\leq n}p_{i}^{\beta_{i}(n)}$, where:

$$\beta_{i}(n)=\alpha_{i}(n)-\alpha_{i}(n-1)$$

Note an important propertie of $\beta_{i}(n)$:

$\beta_{i}(p_{j})=\delta_{i,j}$, this is because the unicity of the canonical decomposition:

$$n=p_{j}=\prod_{p_{i}\leq p_{j}}p_{i}^{\beta_{i}(p_{j})}$$

Let's use this resoults to probe the followin hypothesis:

**Hypothesis**

$\forall N > 1, \exists k \in \{0,1,2,...,N-1\}$, such that, the prime factorization of $N^{2}-k^{2}$ always has at least one solution in the form $p_{1}p_{2}$, $(N^{2}-k^{2}=p_{1}p_{2})$, where $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are prime numbers and $p_1 \leq p_2$.

we know that:

$$(N-k)=\prod_{p_{i}\leq N-k}p_{i}^{\beta_{i}(N-k)}$$

$$(N+k)=\prod_{p_{i}\leq N+k}p_{i}^{\beta_{i}(N+k)}$$

then:

$$(N-k)(N+k)=\prod_{p_{i}\leq N+k}p_{i}^{\beta_{i}(N-k)+\beta_{i}(N+k)}$$

$\displaystyle N^{2}-k^{2}=\prod_{p_{i}\leq N+k}p_{i}^{\gamma_{i}(N,k)}=p_1 p_2$, where:

$\gamma_{i}(N,k)=\beta_{i}(N-k)+\beta_{i}(N+k)$, then:

$\gamma_{i}(N,k)=\alpha_{i}(N-k)-\alpha_{i}(N-k-1)+\alpha_{i}(N+k)-\alpha_{i}(N+k-1)$

This is where I need help to find some error in the reasoning:

Then, due to the uniqueness of prime factorization, we have: $\gamma_{1}(N,k)=1; \gamma_{2}(N,k)=1; \gamma_{s}(N,k)=0$.

We can use the equations $\gamma_{1}(N,k)=1$, $\gamma_{2}(N,k)=1$, and $\gamma_{s}(N,k)=0$ other cases, to prove the hypothesis.

To prove that there exists a value of $k$ that satisfies the hypothesis, we can consider the sum of the first two equations:

$\gamma_{1}(N,k)+\gamma_{2}(N,k)=2$

We know that $\gamma_{1}(N,k)$ and $\gamma_{2}(N,k)$ are both either equal to $1$ or equal to $0$, so their sum can only be $0$, $1$, or $2$. But since $\gamma_{1}(N,k) + \gamma_{2}(N,k) = 2$, the sum of their values is always less than or equal to $2$, $\gamma_{1}(N,k) + \gamma_{2}(N,k) \leq 2$.

This implies that there exist two distinct prime factors $p_1$ and $p_2$ such that $N^{2}-k^{2}=p_{1}p_{2}$ and $p_1 \leq p_2$, which satisfies the hypothesis.

To prove that such a $k$ always exists, we can consider that $\gamma_{s}(N,k)=0$, which implies that all prime factors of $N^{2}-k^{2}$ are distinct from $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$. Since the product of two distinct prime factors is always greater than twice the smaller factor, we can ensure that there always exists a value of $k$ such that $p_1 \leq k < N$ and $p_1p_2=N^2-k^2 \geq 2k+1$ (since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are primes and therefore greater than or equal to $2$). This is a is a consequence of Bertrand's postulate, which states that there is always a prime number between $n$ and $2n$ for any integer $n > 1$. This property ensures that there are always enough prime factors available to satisfy the conditions required for the existence of a value of $k$ such that $p_1 \leq k < N$ and $p_1p_2=N^2-k^2 \geq 2k+1$.

Thus, the existence of a value of $k$ that satisfies the hypothesis is proven.

As we have shown earlier, for any positive integer $N$ greater than $1$, there exists a $k$ in the range from $0$ to $N-1$ such that $N^2 - k^2$ is the product of two primes, where one is less than or equal to the other. Therefore, for that value of $k$, we can write:

$$N^2−k^2=(N−k)(N+k)=p_lp_m$$

Where $p_l$ and $p_m$ are the two primes that are factors of $N^2 - k^2$. Furthermore, since one factor is greater than the other, we can without loss of generality take $p_l \leq p_m$. Therefore, the statement is true for every $N>1$.

Therefore for every $N>1$, there exists a $k$, $0\leq k\leq N-1$, such that $N-k=p_l$ and $N+k=p_m$, where $p_l\leq p_m$, $p_l$ and $p_m$ are primes. This is because $p_l$ and $p_m$ are factors of $(N-k)(N+k)$ and moreover, $p_l \leq N-k < N < N+k \leq p_m$. Therefore, $p_l$ and $p_m$ must be equal to $N-k$ and $N+k$ (in some order) since they are the only prime numbers between $N-k$ and $N+k$. Note that: $$\gamma_{i}(N,k)=\alpha_{i}(N-k)-\alpha_{i}(N-k-1)+\alpha_{i}(N+k)-\alpha_{i}(N+k-1)$$

$$\gamma_{i}(N,k)=\alpha_{i}(p_{l})-\alpha_{i}(p_{l}-1)+\alpha_{i}(p_{m})-\alpha_{i}(p_{m}-1)$$

$$\gamma_{i}(N,k)=\beta_{i}(p_{l})+\beta_{i}(p_{m})$$

then:

$$\gamma_{i}(N,k)=\delta_{i,l}+\delta_{i,m}=\begin{cases}
 1 &\text{if $i=l$}\\
 1 & \text{if $i=m$}\\
 0 &  other-case\\
\end{cases}$$

So, adding term by term, for every $N>1$, there exists a $k$, $0 \leq k \leq N-1$, such that $2N = p_l + p_m$, where $p_l \leq p_m$, $p_l$ and $p_m$ are primes.

So, for every $N>1$, exits $p_l$ and $p_m$, $p_l \leq p_m$, primes, such that $2N=p_l+p_m$.

Comment: You do realise that $N^2-k^2$ is either odd or divisible by $4$? This means that $\gamma_1$ can never be 1, contrary to your "hypothesis".

Comment: $10^{2}-3^{2}=7*13$, $10^{2}-7^{2}=3*17$,  $11^{2}-0^{2}=11*11$,  $11^{2}-6^{2}=5*17$,  $11^{2}-8^{2}=3*19$

Comment: What are $m,l$ in the definition of $\gamma_i$?

Comment: @AlexR. If $l$, let's say, is equal to $2$ ($l=2$), then $\gamma_{2} $ is the exponet asosiated to $p_{2}=3$ (the second prime number).

Comment: What confuses me is your reasoning for $\gamma_i$ in terms of $\beta_i$. It's certainly true that $\beta_i(p_j)=\delta_{ i,j}$ (but certainly not true for $\beta_i(n)$ for $n$ not prime), but you're concluding $\gamma_i=1$ by first implying that you've found a prime $N-k=p_l$ to force $\gamma_l=1$ and therefore there's a prime $p_m=N+k$.  What I'm saying is, your proof that $N-k=p_l$ is cyclical because you assume that such primes $p_l,p_m$ exists in the first place. It's true that if you can show $N^2-k^2 = p_lp_m$ for some primes $p_l,p_m$ that would imply the Goldbach conjecture.

Comment: $10^{2}-3^{2}=7*13$, $10^{2}-7^{2}=3*17$,  $11^{2}-0^{2}=11*11$,  $11^{2}-6^{2}=5*17$,  $11^{2}-8^{2}=3*19$

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, in the above proof you have, are you at any point implying that you've proven your hypothesis? Because if the answer is no, then the rest of your reasoning is perfectly fine. If for every $N$ you can find a $k$ such that $N^2-k^2=p_lp_m$, then this proves the Goldbach conjecture. Your notation is hard to parse, so it wasn't clear to me if you're also trying to prove your hypothesis.

Comment: i.e. there's nothing wrong with your proof, given your assumption of the hypothesis.